# When a r.v. admits mean and variance?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

If $X$ is a r.v. on $(\Omega,\mathcal E, P)$ I have

$E(X)=\int_\Omega X \, dP$

$\mathrm{Var}(X)=\int_\Omega (X-E(X))^2 \, dP=\int_\Omega X^2 \, dP - 2E(X) \int_\Omega X \, dP + E(X)^2 $

so

$X \in L^1(P) \Rightarrow E(X) < +\infty$

and (because $P$ finite $\Rightarrow L^2(P) \subseteq L^1(P)$)

$X \in L^2(P) \Rightarrow\mathrm{Var}(X) < +\infty$

Now I would like to find similar sufficient conditions on the pmf and the pdf.
For the continuous case, if $X$ admits a density $f$

$E(X)=\int_\mathbb R x f(x) dx$

$\mathrm{Var}(X)=\int_\mathbb R (x - E(X))^2 f(x) dx=\int_\mathbb R x^2 f(x) dx - 2E(X)\int_\mathbb R x f(x) dx + E(X)^2 $

so it's enough for the existence of mean and variance that

$\int_\mathbb R |x|f(x) dx < +\infty$ and $\int_\mathbb R (x-E(X))^2f(x) dx < +\infty$

Is there any condition on $f$ such that the previous integral converge?

(I already find that $\int_\mathbb R x^2 f(x) dx < +\infty \Rightarrow \int_\mathbb R |x|f(x) dx < +\infty$ then $\mathrm{Var}(X)<+\infty \Rightarrow E(X)<+\infty$).

Answer (score 0):

You need $\int_{\mathbb R} x^2 \; f(x)\; dx < \infty$.
You already said you need $X \in L^2(P)$, and $E(X^2) = \int_{\mathbb R} x^2\; f(x)\; dx$ for a random variable with a density.

Comment: Ok Robert, let me ask you a question.

Comment: OK, I'm letting you.

Comment: Is there any condition on $f$ that make me sure that $\int_\mathbb R x^2 f(x) dx < +\infty$ or $\int_\mathbb R x f(x) dx < +\infty$??